# How to pass data to Stripe checkout with Rails and HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, stripe-payments

I have a signup form with First Name, Last Name, Email and Phone, and then a Pay with Card Stripe Checkout button. Once the user fills out the form, Stripe Checkout asks for Email Address. How can I get the user entered email address in the form to auto fill the email address field in Stripe Checkout.

Here's my current code:

```
        .field
          = f.label :"Email:"
          = f.text_field :email
        %br  
        .actions
          %script.stripe-button{ src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
                data: {email: "thisemail@carriesover.com", amount: @level.price*100, description: @level.name, key: Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key}}
```

If I hardcode the email address in the Stripe Checkout script, it works. Can I use jQuery to pass it over? If so, how?

Comment: If you get it in JS on the same page then you can't this way. You need to use Custom Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) and pass the email in the `email` parameter of `handler.open()`

Comment: @koopajah thanks! it looks like it broke this line though: `@registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"])` Not sure where stripe_params[] comes from.

Comment: If you use custom checkout you get the token in the `token()` callback and at that point you have to post the token id and the user email yourself to your server

Answer (score 0):

I did so like this:

```
    = javascript_include_tag "https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js",
      :class => "stripe-button",
      :"data-key" => "#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]}",
      :"data-description" => "charged upon appointment confirmation",
      :"data-amount" => total.to_s,
      :"data-image" => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xx
      :"data-label" => "Request Appointment",
      :"data-panel-label" => "Pre-Authorize",
      :"data-name" => "Pre-Authorize Payment",
      :"data-email" => @current_user.email
```

Hope it helps you.